# Ĉu "ne legis" signifas "didn't read" aŭ "hasn't read"?

Tags: translation, verbs

> Ŝi ne legis ĝin.

Kial Duolingo tradukas la frazon al "She hasn't read it", anstataŭ al "She didn't read it"?

Answer (score 1):

While in English the difference between *has'nt read it* and *didn't read it* seems to be quite subtle - at least for none-native speakers, in Esperanto you can use the [Participle](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/participoj/index.html) to express different aspects very nicely.

By using

- -ant-
- -int-
- -ont-

you have already a big range of expressions. You can actually say things easily that you need a lot of words for in German. I think in English it's quite similar, but I'm not native in English.

Combined with

- -estas
- -estis
- -estos

there are more possibilities than you'll ever need. Please don't take me to court about the following translations. As I mentioned: I'm not a native English speaker. But you get the idea.

> ŝi ne legis - she did not read
>
> ŝi ne estas leginta - she has not read
>
> ŝi ne estis leganta - she was not reading
>
> ŝi ne estis leginta - she had not read
>
> ...

Comment: Koran dankon, Sinjor' @Olafant pro via helpo.

Answer (score 0):

There are three tenses in Esperanto: the past, the present and the future tense. The simple verbs (those ending in *is, -as* and *os* and without any additional pre- or postfixes) have an [aspect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) called [*la reala modo*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/reala/index.html). They simply express acts and states that are real.

You can say that English also has a single past tense, but the aspects make it look different, i.e. "didn't read" and "hasn't read" as just two aspects of the same tense. They both can be used to show *la reala modo*.

Comment: So what? Is that translation wrong, and should be changed to "didn't read"?

Comment: No, the Esperanto sentence simply describes an act that happened in the past. I'm not sufficiently skilled in English to speak about the differences in aspect between those two translations, but I strongly suspect that without further info or context both will do.

Comment: If someone said to me "I haven't read that book" I would understand them to mean that they have never read the book. If they said "I didn't read it," that would mean that they did not read it in a specific period of time. For instance, they were asked to read it in preparation for a class, but didn't. For example, "Did you read the book the teacher assigned us last week?" Answer: "I was too busy. I didn't read it. Actually I have read that book, but it was a long time ago." But in Esperanto, "ŝi ne legis ĝin" could be used for either meaning, depending on the context.

Comment: Dankon Sinjoro @AJWentworth pro via respondo.

Answer (score 0):

> She hasn't read it. = Ŝi ne estas leginta ĝin.

But for verbosity of the Esperanto form, one often uses past tense instead of perfect tense:

> She hasn't read it. = Ŝi ne legis ĝin.

For a help language an entirely practical solution.

Border line usage applies also `legintas` for `estas leginta` saving syllables.